# Create a function which returns 1 if x < 0, returns 0 otherwise using only bitwise operations

Tags: c, bit-manipulation

This is the code i've been able to come up:

```
isNegative(int a)
    int result;
    result = (a >> 31);
    result = result & 1;
```

This works fine for all cases except for, 0x80000000.
Please help as to how I can fix this code to be correct for all cases.

Comment: `0x80000000` is negative (for a 32-bit int), and your function does return 1 for it. What is the problem?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11438794/is-the-size-of-c-int-2-bytes-or-4-bytes probably shouldn't assume a 32 bit `int`, though that might be accurate on some systems

Comment: Actually, since right-shifting a negative integer is implementation defined, maybe there is your problem.

Comment: @erik258: *some systems* -> *most systems*

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Checking whether a number is positive or negative using bitwise operators](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3779202/checking-whether-a-number-is-positive-or-negative-using-bitwise-operators)

Answer (score 3):

The code posted has implementation behavior: Right shifting a signed negative value is specified as *implementation-defined* by the C Standard:

> **6.5.7 Bitwise shift operators**
>
> The result of `E1 >> E2` is `E1` right-shifted `E2` bit positions. If `E1` has an unsigned type or if `E1` has a signed type and a nonnegative value, the value of the result is the integral part of the quotient of `E1`/2<sup>`E2`</sup>. If `E1` has a signed type and a negative value, the resulting value is implementation-defined.

Conversely, conversion from signed `int` to `unsigned` is fully defined and right shifting the unsigned value will work as expected.

Note that if the width of the `unsigned` type is exactly 32 bits, masking the result of the right shift is not required. Regarding the behavior on `INT_MIN`: if signed integers are represented using two's complement, converting `INT_MIN` to `unsigned` produces `0x80000000`, which gives `1` when shifted right by 31 bits, as expected since `INT_MIN` is negative.

Here is a modified version:

```
#include <stdint.h>

// assuming 32-bit ints
int isNegative(int32_t a) {
    uint32_t result = a;
    return result >> 31;
}
```

Comment: Would this work in 32-bit excess-2^31 representation? Not that I know any such implementation.

Comment: @Nelfeal: excess notations are not standard representations for signed integers in the C Standard. As a matter of fact, the upcoming C23 Standard will only support 2's complement representations, with or without padding bits.  Note also that the most significant bit in excess notations is the complement of the sign bit: `0` for negative, `1` for positive.

Answer (score 1):

Here is an implementation that doesn't rely on implementation defined right-shifting and doesn't assume the size of an `int` (but assumes two's complement representation):

```
#include <limits.h>

int isNegative(int a) {
    return !!(a & INT_MIN);
}
```

Comment: Interesting alternative, but does not work for non 2's complement representations

Comment: @chqrlie Pretty sure it also works in sign-magnitude and 1's complement if you consider `-0 < +0`. I suppose you could add a `&& a != -0` (or `&& a != 0`? I don't know how these representations would work with the `-0`).

Comment: I'm afraid you miss somthing: `INT_MIN` has all bits set on both of these representations, so `!!(a & INT_MIN);` evaluates to `0` only for `+0` and `-0`.

Comment: @chqrlie Good point, though I think this only applies to sign-magnitude. `INT_MIN` in 1's complement should be 127 and represented as `10000000`.

Comment: You are correct, `INT_MIN` has the same representation in ones' complement and two's complement representations, but your expression will also evaluate to `1` for `-0` which may or may not be expected.

Comment: Note however that `!` is not considered a *bitwise operation*. You could also write `return (a & INT_MIN) / INT_MIN;` but `/` is not a *bitwise operation* either.

Comment: @chqrlie True, but technically, neither is a cast to an unsigned type. The question is not well formulated in my opinion (as are many of these "only bitwise operations" questions).

Comment: Note that there is no cast in my code, just an implicit conversion... and I agree with your assessment :)